# How to add advertisement banner to list in ionic

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm building this, application in which I load a list from an API. But after loading 3 list items, there should be an empty space to add advertisements. The advertisement is being loaded out of my own API. My problem is that I do not know how to add that empty space between the data. I'll add the link to a picture below and you'll see what I mean.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same issue. What I've done is, I iterated over the list with an index and if the index was greater than n number then I would show some recommended ads.

I.E:

```
<div *ngFor="let business of businesses; let i = index">
   <ion-list class="business-list" *ngIf="i <= 4">
       <business [business]="business"> </business>
    </ion-list>
    <!-- Here at the fifth position of my list I want to display the ads -->
    <div class="card-container" *ngIf='i == 4'>
        <h4>Recommended</h4>
          <ion-slides>
            <div *ngFor="let info of ads; let j = index">
              <div *ngIf='j<2'> <!-- This is because I only want 2 ads -->
                <ion-slide>
                  <business [business]="info" [isRecommended]="true"></business>
                </ion-slide>
              </div>
            </div>
         </ion-slides>
     </div>
      <!-- Items to be shown after the the ads are done -->
      <ion-list class="business-list" *ngIf='i > 4'>
        <business [business]="business"> </business>
      </ion-list>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If each ion-item is a component, you can use `ng-content` to put some template inside the component.

```
<my-comp [event]="event" *ngFor="let event of listEvents?.event; let i = index;">
    <advertisement *ngIf="(i+1) % stepAds === 0"></advertisement>
  </my-comp>
```

my-comp.html

```
<ion-item>Data</ion-item>
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

---

**Otherwise**, if you dont have components, you can use the same logic with ng-template

```
<ng-template *ngFor="let i of items; let i = index">
    <ion-item>Data</ion-item>
    <div *ngIf="(i + 1) % 3 === 0">advertisement<div>
</ng-template
```

The `ng-template` will not be outputed in the DOM.

Hope it help you.